# How to style individual inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following code html code:

```
<!--SLIDING BUTTONS --> 
<div id="resblogresu">
    <!--RESUME OF MAIN PAGE --> 
    <h2><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></h2>
    <!--BLOG OF MAIN PAGE --> 
    <h2><a href="blog.html"> Blog </a></h2>
    <!-- MT RESULTS OF MAIN PAGE --> 
    <div id="MTR">
        <h2><a href="mtresults.html"> Muay Thai<br/> results </a></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS code:

```
#resblogresu h2,div {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}
#MTR h2{

}
```

Now, whenever I try to style id="MTR" by itself, by trying to move it up a couple of pixels, the remaining elements in id="resblogresu" get styled as well.

How can I make it that

1) Resume, blog, and MT Results are all aligned horizontally
2) Resume,blog,and MT results will each have their own top,bottom,right,and left spacing properties

My guess: perhaps it's not a good idea to have all three in the same div tag.

Comment: FYI, `#resblogresu h2,div` is targeting `#resblogresu h2` as well as *all* `<div>` elements, *including* `#resblogresu`. Perhaps your selector should be; `#resblogresu h2, #resblogresu div`?

Comment: "Now, whenever I try to style id="MTR" by itself, by trying to move it up a couple of pixels, the remaining elements in id="resblogresu" get styled as well." — *how* are you trying to do this? You should provide a [mcve]. It would be best to use an [inline live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: First of all you shouldn't use px. You should use vpx or vw/vh.

Comment: @George thank you, I would have never caught that.

Comment: @RijadHadzic Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

So first off, you have the right idea putting all three together, but the container (aka div element) needs to be configured to display 3 inline block elements the way you want it too. Below is the way I style your document. Use grid, and then style each element accordingly. There are several ways of doing this and if I were you I would check out:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_navbar.asp
2. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

also as a note, the way you were selecting elements with CSS was more complex than it needed to be. For a simple script like this try selecting each element separably so you can style each element independently from the other elements. This will allow you to have more control, and better understanding over whats going on with your website. Later if you want compress your css you can clean it up by using group selectors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 20vw 20vw 20vw;
            width: 100%;
            width: 100vw;
            border: 1px solid #0F0;
        }

        .a{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        .b{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        .c{
            margin: 10px 0 0 0;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        #MTR h2 {}

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!--SLIDING BUTTONS -->
    <div class="grid-container">
        <!--RESUME OF MAIN PAGE -->
        <div class="a">
            <h2>
                <a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <!--BLOG OF MAIN PAGE -->
        <div class="b">
            <h2>
                <a href="blog.html"> Blog </a>
            </h2>
        </div
              <!-- MT RESULTS OF MAIN PAGE -->
        <div class="c">
            <h2>
                <a href="mtresults.html"> Muay Thai<br /> results </a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```